# Order list by parent and child and parent of the child

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to order List that should look like this

1. Parent

   - Child1 (simultaneously children and parent)

     - Child2 (Children of Child1)
   - Child3

In using Class that contain information's about ID, ParentID and etc.

I'm trying to make this work using LINQ and tried different solution but no one work completely, I know that with recursively function will work (but really don't like that), can someone help me to make working with LINQ ?

i tried this code but Child2 don't appearing.

```
List<Person> orderedList = new List<Person>();
            persons.ForEach(x => {
                if (x.ParentID == 0) {
                    orderedList.Add(x);
                    orderedList.AddRange(persons.Where(child => child.ParentID == x.Id));
                }
            });
```

For those who are voting "negative" remember no one was god at programming at the beginning, if i come here that means that I'm struggle to fix the problem for x hours. And also if you think that my English is bad i know that already, I'm not born to speak English perfectly but those who wants to help will help. :)

Whole Code

```
        public class Person{
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string MenuName { get; set; }
            public int? ParentID { get; set; }
            public string isHidden { get; set; }
            public string LinkURL { get; set; }
        }
        public static List<Person> AddPersons(){
            var persons = new List<Person>();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\AceDuk\Desktop\Navigation.csv")){
                var line = reader.ReadLine(); //Da se izbegne headerot
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null){
                    var values = line.Split(';');

                    if (values[2] == "NULL") {
                        values[2] = "0";
                    }

                    persons.Add(new Person(){
                        Id = Int32.Parse(values[0]),
                        MenuName = values[1],
                        ParentID = Int32.Parse(values[2]),
                        isHidden = values[3],
                        LinkURL = values[4]
                    });
                }
            }
            persons.RemoveAll(x => x.isHidden == "True"); //Izbrisi gi site sto se hidden ne gi pokazuvaj..
            //persons = persons.OrderBy(x => x.MenuName).ToList(); //Ordered
            persons = persons.OrderBy(x => x.LinkURL).ToList(); //Ordered
            return persons;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args){
            List<Person> persons = AddPersons();

            List<Person> orderedList = new List<Person>();
            persons.ForEach(x => {
                if (x.ParentID == 0) {
                    orderedList.Add(x);
                    orderedList.AddRange(persons.Where(child => child.ParentID == x.Id));
                }
            });

            foreach (var item in orderedList) {
                Console.WriteLine(item.MenuName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Programming doesn't involve "indent". What do you mean by "indent" in a programming context?

Comment: misspelled, edited :)

Comment: LINQ is really terrible at working with hierarchical data. There are a few decent options involving loops and data structures (not LINQ), but you haven't explained why you don't like the recursion option. Recursion is a very good fit for what you're describing, whereas anything else is probably going to be clunky by comparison.

Comment: I've used recursion hundreds of times to solve issues like this.  Linq is not meant for this type of code.

Comment: I don't know maybe because don't have clue about how to do it recursively... i think maybe creating first Tree from the List and then traversing elements and printing..

Comment: FYI, don't use `List<T>.ForEach` in place of a simple `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Create a double-ended queue (deque) data structure by extending a linked list:

```
public class Deque<T> : LinkedList<T> {
    public void Enqueue(T item) => AddLast(item);
    public T Dequeue() {
        var item = First.Value;
        RemoveFirst();
        return item;
    }
    public void EnqueueRange(IEnumerable<T> items) {
        foreach (var item in items)
            Enqueue(item);
    }

    public void Push(T item) => AddFirst(item);
    public T Pop() => Dequeue();
    public void PushRange(IEnumerable<T> items) {
        foreach (var item in items)
            Push(item);
    }

    public T Peek() => Last.Value;
}
```

Now, create a mapping from `Id` to children using `ToLookup`:

```
var childrenDictionary = persons.Where(p => p.ParentID != 0).ToLookup(p => p.ParentID);
```

Finally, use the deque to create a working list and add all the root nodes:

```
var workDeque = new Deque<Person>();
workDeque.EnqueueRange(persons.Where(p => p.ParentID == 0));
```

Now you can go through the `workDeque`, adding each root node to the `orderedPersons` and then pushing the children of the node onto `workDeque` to be worked next:

```
var orderedPersons = new List<Person>();

while (workDeque.Count > 0) {
    var nextPerson = workDeque.Dequeue();
    orderedPersons.Add(nextPerson);
    workDeque.PushRange(childrenDictionary[nextPerson.Id]);
}
```